# Format a value that is under 1.00 with {0:C}?

Tags: .net, format, currency

If I have the value 0.0042 returned and I pass this to:

string.Format("{0:C}",....);

It displays $0 as the results when I want it to actually display:

$0.0042

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"C" is the default currency format string, which will always truncate your number to two decimal places.  You need to specify the number of decimal places if you're dealing with tiny fractions of a cent.

Try

```
string.Format("{0:C4}",....);
```

More currency formatting options [can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#CFormatString).

Comment: Ok, this works, but lets say I have the value 1245.2993 and I do C4 as the Format, then it will display 1245.2993, but in this case, I want to just display 1245.29 for example.  Is there a way to specify this?

Comment: Format strings aren't conditional - either you want four decimal places or two.  You'll have to use conditional logic to check your number beforehand and use the appropriate format string.

Comment: string.Format won't do this automatically. If you want different formats depending on the value, you'll have to check the value in code.

Comment: Ok, I had a feeling it would have to be a code check. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

```
string.Format("{0:C4}",....);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pardon the question necromancy, but for anyone reading this today, here's a custom format string we use. It matches the standard "C" format for U.S. currency, except that it will optionally show a third or fourth decimal place if present. This should work great for formatting a SQL Server money value with fractions of a cent.

```
// String.Format() example
string.Format("{0:$#,0.00##;($#,0.00##);$\0\.\0\0}", someDecimalValue)
// Decimal.ToString() example
someDecimalValue.ToString("$#,0.00##;($#,0.00##);$\0\.\0\0")
```

Because it's not using the standard "C" format, it's not sensitive to locale. Extra consideration should be given for applications that require internationalization.